# Click on EditText doesn't show softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, actionbarsherlock, android-softkeyboard

I am using ActionBarSherlock, in the ActionBar i have this custom layout to appear when i click on the searchIcon.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.on_search_icon_clicked,null, false);
view.findViewById(R.id.search_image).setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        EditText searchET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_editText);
        String s = searchET.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Searching for: " + s,1000).show();
                    }
        });

menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search)
        .setActionView(view)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
        return true;
}
```

on_search_icon_clicked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/seach_icon" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_image"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, `i click on the SearchIcon` ---> `i get the custom layout with editText and ImageView` ---> `click on editText, opens softkeyboard` ---> `enters string and clicks the imageView` ---> `shows me the toast.`

Its fine till here.

The problem is:

i `close the softkeyboard using device back button` ---> then `close the custom layout using ActionBar Home icon click` ---> now `click the searchIcon again, which reopens the custom layout, with editText filled with previously searched string` ---> `click on the editText, the softkeyboard doesn't open up` (here is the problem).

Please help, i have no idea why its not working as expected.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this problem before and here is my solution

```
//your_menu
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:icon="@drawable/btn_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/on_search_icon_clicked"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
   />
</menu>


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{       
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    mSearchbar = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    View actionview = mSearchbar.getActionView();
    mEtSearchbar = ((EditText) actionview.findViewById(R.id.search_editText));
    mEtSearchbar.setOnEditorActionListener(this);       
    mEtSearchbar.addTextChangedListener(this);      
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.menu_search:                  
            mEtSearchbar.clearFocus();
             (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mEtSearchbar.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
                    mEtSearchbar.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP , 0, 0, 0));
                }
             }, 100);
            break;          
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

mEtSearchbar ~ your searchET

Comment: can you please explain, why i am getting this problem and what exactly you solution does??

Comment: actually this won't work, i believe. Because, R.id.menu_search which in my case R.id.search_image in the switch block doesn't get to work because, its not in the menu items, it only appears when i click the searchIcon(this is the actual menu item).

Comment: No no,menu_search  is the id of your search menu item. menu.add("Search") -> try to set id for this menu item.

Comment: Just added more details. Try it and let me know if your problem  resolved

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. But do you know the reason why it didn't work the previous way??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it didn't work the normal way but I think that is a framework problem.

Comment: and 1 more small issue. I am using SingleLine = "true" in the EditText of the custom layout. so i expect "done" key in place of nextLine key. But it shows "next".

Comment: You should use android:imeOptions="actionSearch" on your EditText for search function

Comment: yeah but when i click on the searchButton of the softkeyboard, it doesn't get minimized it shows newLine button now, as if its now focused on next EditText